# Animating the action bar in fragment transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which is using the one-activity-multiple-fragments architecture using navigation component.

For each fragment, I have a slide in/out animation like so:

`anim_in.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

`anim_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

`nav_graph.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.monettests.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/anim_in"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/anim_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim_out"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_feedbackFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/anim_in"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/anim_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim_out"
            app:destination="@id/feedbackFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.monettests.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="Settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedbackFragment"
        android:name="com.example.monettests.FeedbackFragment"
        android:label="Send Feedback"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feedback" />
</navigation>
```

Navigation code in `MainFragment`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menuMain_settingsItem -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_settingsFragment)
                    true
                }

                R.id.menuMain_feedbackItem -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_feedbackFragment)
                    true
                }

                else -> {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```

The problem with this is that it just animates the fragment itself but not the action bar.

What I have tried:

- Manually animating the action bar in each fragment using listeners (unsuccessful)
- Searching documentation for a way to do this (tried for hours but unsuccessful - shocked that there isn't a way to do this in the SDK)

I understand that this is desired fragment behavior, but I want to give the end user the **illusion of animating between different pages** and for that it's best if the action bar itself is part of the transition.

Is there any way to have a fragment transition that animates the fragment and the action bar, similar to how it's done with activities?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: no.................

Comment: I removed actionBar from the activity and used a layout as actionBar in each fragment